# time comparision in rails for postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a column name `late` with datatype `time without time zone`. my requirement is to read all the rows which is late more than by 1 hours. I have to query through my rails application. In table column value is like `00:31:00` but in rails it is like 
`2000-01-01 00:31:00 UTC`. How to query directly or by using ActiveRecords?

Answer (score 1):

When you can directly access the time in rails as '2000-01-01 00:31:00 UTC', then use the code

```
require 'time'
standard_time_for_comparison = '2000-01-01 00:31:00 UTC'
(Time.now - Time.parse(standard_time_for_comparison))/3600 > 1
```

Change standard_time_for_comparison  according to your needs.